# Configuration error[Application secret not set]

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I got this error running Play 2.4 server in production mode:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, @6mh5cjo5l: Configuration error
  while locating play.api.libs.CryptoConfigParser
  while locating play.api.libs.CryptoConfig

...

Caused by: play.api.PlayException: Configuration error[Application secret not set]
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default Play template uses the following:

```
play.crypto.secret="changeme"
```

in the `application.conf` which needs to be changed for use in production.  Play provides an utility to generate a random secret for you:

```
./activator playGenerateSecret
```

with which you can then populate as an environment variable:

```
APPLICATION_SECRET=...
```

and in `conf/application.conf` ensure the following:

```
play.crypto.secret="changeme"
play.crypto.secret=${?APPLICATION_SECRET}
```

which as the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ApplicationSecret) explains:

> The second line in that configuration sets the secret to come from an
>   environment variable called APPLICATION_SECRET if such an environment
>   variable is set, otherwise, it leaves the secret unchanged from the
>   previous line.

Then the error will go away.

Comment: Man, you're genius. I was fixing this problem for about 10hours... I'm deploying an app on Heroku and had internal errors without setting crypto.key to a different one. Use "./activator playGenerateSecret" to generate one from your project folder. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that can still stumble upon this issue and is not using `activator` yet `sbt` as I am.

Just follow the documentation on Play 2.x page ([Play 2.4 example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ApplicationSecret))

The "magic" command is

`sbt playUpdateSecret`

This will both generate the secret and update your conf file. So this command saved me a lot of work and discovering.

Cheers.