# Play Framework deploy failed: "the application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure"

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I'm deploying on Heroku a web application developed with Play Framework.
The deploy fails returning this error:

```
[error] p.a.l.c.CryptoConfigParser - The application secret has not been set, and we are in prod mode. Your application is not secure.
```

What does it means that "we are in prod mode"? Where do I set the mode? I have to change this because it's not a production environment.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuration error\[Application secret not set\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981261/configuration-errorapplication-secret-not-set)

Comment: Even though this is not your production *environment*, you still want to run your app in production *mode* on Heroku.

Comment: See this - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret#Production-configuration-file

Answer (score 7):

Put this into your conf/application.conf

**Play 2.5**

```
play.crypto.secret="changethissosomethingsecret"
```

**Play 2.6+**

```
play.http.secret.key="changethissosomethingsecret"
```

[You can also start your application with a source with a secret key as a parameter.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ApplicationSecret)

Comment: This is deprecated now. Play recommends using ```play.http.secret.key = "changethissosomethingsecret"```

Comment: using play.http.secret.key="changethissosomethingsecret" helped. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up different keys based on the Play version that your application is using.

#### What version of play are you using?

Either look at `com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin` version inside your project's `plugins.sbt` or if you have a GNU compatible shell, execute the following command:

```
find . -name "plugins.sbt" -exec grep -PHin --color=always 'com.typesafe.play.*sbt-plugin.*%\s*"\K.*?(?=")' {} \;
```

Proceed to the next step, once you know the version number of play used by your app.

---

#### What is the key to use in application.conf based on play version?

[Play 2.3.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ApplicationSecret): `application.secret` (defaults to `changeme`) 
[Play 2.4.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ApplicationSecret): `play.crypto.secret` (defaults to `changeme`) 
[Play 2.5.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret): `play.crypto.secret` (defaults to `changeme`) 
[Play 2.6.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret): `play.http.secret.key` (defaults to `changeme`)

As you can see it is not consistent, but what is consistent is:

1. In the above versions you can override the secret using `APPLICATION_SECRET` environment variable/property (so, something like `APPLICAITION_SECRET="changed" sbt "runProd 9001"`)
2. The default value in each case is `changeme`

---

*The next two options were tested on  Play `v2.6.x`, but according to the documentation, should work with the same commands for `v2.4.x` and `v2.5.x`.* 
***The only exception is `v2.3.x` which uses `play-generate-secret` and `play-update-secret` respectively***

#### How do I get sbt to generate a key for me?

Run the following command from within the directory of your play application (tested with sbt v1.1.6 and play v2.6.x):

```
$ sbt playGenerateSecret | grep -i 'generated'
[info] Generated new secret: ^7UubY[rFXzkN:v6TB9WL/lfGsP61/vzAHA9tdZNZ@nALH=TEztKAlTC>xz;VUXw
```

You can manually copy the above as the value for the key (based on play framework version as noted before) OR, you can use the suggestion below.

#### How do I get sbt to update existing key in `application.conf` automatically?

Same as above, run the following command from the root directory of your play framework app:

```
$ sbt playUpdateSecret | grep -i "secret"
[info] Generated new secret: Kz?fHm_I[wt^Onp[@cr<:`ttrQi]KMsdDs>22hEF?RhkoanQ7gA6NAjL33EV2^Xt
[info] Updating application secret in /Users/blah/someplayapp/conf/application.conf
[warn] Did not find application secret in /Users/blah/someplayapp/conf/application.conf
[warn] Adding application secret to start of file
```

Couple of things to note about this command:

1. `playUpdateSecret` will update the existing secret or add a secret to `application.conf` if it is not present.
2. This commands looks for the key and/or adds/updates it in `application.conf` **only**. This is important if you are following the [Best Practice](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret#Production-configuration-file).
   This best practice refers to creating a separate `production.conf` that overrides this key from application.conf:

   include "application"

   play.http.secret.key="somesecretkey"

and then run your app like so:

```
/path/to/yourapp/bin/yourapp -Dconfig.file=/path/to/production.conf
```

As you can see, if you are using `playUpdateSecret` to generate a new secret then it is going to have no effect since it is being overridden by the secret specified in `production.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add an application secret in your conf file.

> play.http.secret.key="changethissosomethingsecret"

Answer (score 0):

> Before you run your application in production mode, you need to generate an application secret

You need generate token for application in production mode, using `activator playGenerateSecret`

[Configuration Application Secret](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ApplicationSecret)

[Link documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#The-application-secret)